# Sort By Last Name Data fetched from API In React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MavT8.png)

I am trying to fetch data from Random user API and create a table of users. I also want to add feature like sort by last name, pagination to show only 10 items per page and add a option button if user wants to see more than. 10 items on the page I am strugging to build that feature any hellp wilbe appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Loader from '../components/Loader/Loader';

import '../util/Fetch.css';
export class Fetch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
    this.sortList.bind(this);
    this.compareBy.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    const url =
      'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us,nz,au&seed=foobar';
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(parsedJSON => {
        this.setState({
          users: parsedJSON.results,
         isLoading: false
        });
      })
        .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error));
    }

    compareBy(key) {
      return function(a, b) {
        if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
        if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
        return 0;
      };
    }

    sortList(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.state.users];
    console.log(
      arrayCopy.map(user => {
        return user.name.first;
      })
    );
    arrayCopy
      .map(user => {
        return user.name.last;
      })
      .sort(this.compareBy(key));
    this.setState({ users: arrayCopy });
  }
}
render() {
const { users } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    {this.state.isLoading ? (
      <Loader />
    ) : (
      <div className="table-container">
        <div className="pag-header">
          <div>
            <ul className="pag-box">
              <h2>List of Users</h2>
              <li>
                <hr />
              </li>
              <li>
                Sort By:{' '}
                <a onClick={() => this.sortList(this.compareBy, 'last')}>
                  Last Name
                  <span>
                    <i className="fas fa-sort-down" />
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul className="pag-box">
              <li>
                items per page
                <label>
                  <select>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="75">75</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>of</li>
              <li>
                <a>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-left" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>
                  <i className="fas fa-angle-right" />
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="responsive-table">
          <li id="table-head" className="table-header">
            <div className="col col-1">First name</div>
            <div className="col col-2">Last Name</div>
            <div className="col col-3">Country</div>
            <div className="col col-4">Address</div>
            <div className="col col-5">City</div>
            <div className="col col-5">State</div>
            <div className="col col-7">Zip</div>
            <div className="col col-8">Phone</div>
          </li>
          <ul className="responsive-table">
            {users.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id.value} className="table-row">
                <div className="col col-1" data-label="First Name">
                  {user.name.first}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-2" data-label="Last Name">
                  {user.name.last}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-3" data-label="Country">
                  {user.nat}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-4" data-label="Address">
                  {user.location.street}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-5" data-label="Address">
                  {user.location.city}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-6" data-label="State">
                  {user.location.state}
                </div>
                <div className="col col-7" data-label="Zip">
                  {user.location.postcode}
                </div>

                <div className="col col-8" data-label="Phone">
                  {user.cell}
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
   </div>
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `sort` function sorts using Unicode points for every character. So the final result will in most cases will be not something you expect. Refer MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can use `lodash` or then use and example they have on the docs to make sure sorting is stable.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There were a number of issues with the code in question, and not enough information was given in the question to really understand the scope of the issue.  A custom solution was worked out across multiple files in the project to resolve the asker's problem, but it is outside the scope of this question to post that solution here.

---

In the last few lines, you're trying to sort `arrayCopy.map(user => user.name.last)` That map will return an array of JUST THE LAST NAME, so like `['jones', 'smith', 'jenkins']`. Then you try to sort THAT array by a key, but that array is a plain old array of strings, and the only "key" it has are the indexes (0, 1, 2, etc)

Instead, you should be doing `arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key))` and `this.sortList('last')` to accomplish the sort and save to state.

```js
compareBy = (key) => {  // no need to bind arrow functions
  return function(a, b) {
    if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
    if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
    return 0;
  };
};

sortList = (key) => {
  let arrayCopy = [...this.state.users];
  arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
  this.setState({ users: arrayCopy });
};
```

EDIT: After looking at your code some more, I see that you are attempting to bind `sortList` and `compareBy`, but you're not actually saving those bound methods anywhere. `this.sortList.bind(this)` returns a bound method, but does not make the original method bound, so whenever you call `this.sortList`, it still is unbound. Changing it into an arrow function (as above) will make it always bound.

EDIT: Now that you have added the render method, we can see the real problem is in your click-handler:

```js
 <a onClick={() => this.sortList(this.compareBy, 'last')}>
```

Here, you're calling this.sortList with TWO parameters, a function (this.compareBy) and a string ('last').  this.sortList only expects one parameter: the string. This line should read:

```js
 <a onClick={() => this.sortList('last')}>
```

Additionally, because you're implementing `this.sortList` in that `onClick` handler as an arrow function, you do not need to bind the `sortList` method, either in your constructor as in your example (which will not work as implemented) or by converting it to an arrow function (as I suggested in my previous edit). The real problem was A) the click handler passing the wrong parameters, and B) mapping the array to an array of strings before sorting it.

Comment: I tried this ``  compareBy(key) {
    return function(a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }

  sortList(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.state.users];
    arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
    this.setState({ users: arrayCopy });
  }`

Comment: Updated my answer with information about needing to bind the sortList and compareBy methods correctly.

Comment: Could you also add how you're using sortList?  Your example doesn't show the click binding or anything.

Comment: One moment I'll add that as well

Comment: Excellent!  your actual problem is your click handler.  `<a onClick={() => this.sortList(this.compareBy, 'last')}>` should be `<a onClick={() => this.sortList('last')}>`.  This is because `this.sortList(...)` only accepts one parameter (`key`, which is a string), and you're passing in two parameters: `this.compareBy`, which is a function, THEN `'last'` the string that should have been the first (and only) parameter.

Comment: Did you ALSO remove that extra .map? are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: yea I removed it no errors in the console but whenever I click the button to sort the list it doesn't work at all

Comment: I'd have to see the updated code to understand why it's not working.  You could either provide a link somewhere, or update your question to include your updated code (but also leave your original code, so that the question still makes sense to anybody coming to this question for the first time).

Comment: Here's the link to the GitHub Repo this might help  - https://github.com/iharmanpannu/users-data

Comment: I see.  you were trying to sort by 'last', but there is no `user.last`, it is `user.name.last`, so we'll need more work.

Comment: hah yea I thought of it too but I have no idea how to get around it

Comment: also, Pagination.state.users does not exist.  That list exists on Fetch.state.users.  Working on fixing that, too

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It would be awesome if you could comment it so I can understand it for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple method to sort array;something like

```
sortList = (key)=>{
 let arrayCopy = [...this.state.users];
 arrayCopy.sort((a,b) => a.name[key] > b.name[key]);
 this.setState({ users: arrayCopy });
}
```